# How to delete hbase column family using java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

We can delete column family with shell as follows:

```
hbase(main):007:0> alter 'sample_table','delete'=>'cf'
```

But I want to delete column family using java.

Is there in any java api available to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with following java api

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
Admin admin = conn.getAdmin();
admin.deleteColumn(TableName.valueOf("sample_table"),
cf.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [HBaseAdmin](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#deleteColumnFamily(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName,%20byte[])) class, it has method deleteColumnFamily. See example below:

```
HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
admin.deleteColumnFamily(TableName.valueOf(yourTableName), 
          yourColumnFamilyNameBytes)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. HBaseAdmin is showing me deprecated and which properties are necessary in conf to delete the table